# Replace broken SSD with adapter and new SSD in another format

Tags: hardware-failure, hardware-detection

Unfortunately the SSD (model: XM-11; the picture below) of my laptop (ASUS UX31) is broken.
The problem is that I don't find a reputable provider who offers such an SSD-model at an acceptable price.

[image]

So I'm planning to get an adapter for this SSD-format and use a new SSD in a more common format.
However, I am doing this for the first time and I am unsure whether I have chosen the adapter correctly and whether I can connect it to the new SSD.

This is the adapter that I chose:

[image]

[online store link](https://www.real.de/product/308383373/?kwd=&source=pla&sid=1197661&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI7Y-03LCS6QIV0u3tCh0LlQgGEAkYASABEgKCbfD_BwE)

And this is the new SSD (Transcend SSD Mts420s120gb M.2 SATA III):

[image]

[online store link](https://www.ebay.de/p/19009698914?iid=352628869316&chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=707-134425-41852-0&mkcid=2&itemid=352628869316&targetid=888516359244&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9042855&poi=&campaignid=1669295758&mkgroupid=90992276282&rlsatarget=pla-888516359244&abcId=1139676&merchantid=7364532&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI09j-sbGS6QIVj7t3Ch3-eQp8EAkYBCABEgJlEfD_BwE)

Can someone tell me if I can easily connect both parts and use them in my laptop?

I know it's a very simple question, but I have no experience with it.

I would be very happy if someone would share their experience with me.

Comment: Looks OK to me, but will that adapter even fit in the laptop?

Comment: I hope it. The model number of my laptop (UX31) and the model number of the adapter (UX31) are matching.

Comment: I am more concerned with the fact that the new SSD fits into the adapter. I'm not sure about that, because the connections don't appear the same. The adapter has a long and a short slot- But the new SSD has two short and a long plug

Comment: Ah, okay. If that’s what you’re concerned about, I can provide an answer soon if nobody else comes first.

Comment: The SATA M.2 drive is NOT compatible with your laptop nor the adapter.

Comment: @Ramhound Why is it not compatible with the adapter?

Comment: @Ramhound And which SSD-model I should use for this adapter?

Comment: @TobKel - You know I cannot make a recommendation like that.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, ok. But why you think that this ssd is not compatible with the adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[M.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2) supports multiple links (USB, PCIe, SATA, ...) in one connector. However, not all hosts can offer all features. That’s what the key on the socket is for: It physically prevents you from installing a card that could not work in the socket.

The adapter’s socket is B-keyed. Usually, this means it supports:

- PCIe ×2
- SATA
- USB 2.0 and 3.0
- Audio, UIM, HSIC, SSIC, I2C and SMBus

Because this is an adapter to a proprietary connector, it most likely in fact does not support most of this. However, since the original SSD uses a SATA connection, it will most definitely support that.

On the expansion card, the keys indicate the features required for the device. The SSD you found has B and M keys. This means it can access the common subset functionality available on B- and M-keyed sockets:

- PCIe ×2
- SATA
- SMBus

Of course, we already know it’s only using SATA.

Some pins are shared between protocols (like USB/PCIe or SATA/PCIe), so not all protocols can be used concurrently. There are many configurations.

If we disregard adapters, the general idea with M.2 is: If the card fits the socket, it’ll work. Of course, reality is a little more complicated. :-)

tl;dr: The SSD you found fits the adapter. The old SSD was SATA, the new SSD is SATA, so you’re all set, if you can squeeze the adapter inside the notebook.

Comment: Everything is working. Thank you!